# QGIS Attribute Table Format (columns and rows)

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, format, timemanager

I am having a Data Format problem with Qgis using the timemanager.
I loaded a layer with timecodes and values for 1 point and finally made it work.
Now i dont have one point, but 250.
Those 250 points get some values which you can see below and i want them all to blink if they are over some value.

My problem is, that i cannot join a table to my layer with those 250 points as the IDs (1,2...) are in a row, not in a column.
Using the time as attribute to to connect the table to the shp points wouldnt make too much sence, as they dont have fix time periods, i get about 8 entrys per seconds but those are not fix.

I also tried to transpose the whole thing and have IDs in the column but the time now in a row. But it doesnt seem as timemanager could read the time in a row, also only as column.

So how do i connect all these toghether?

250 Fix points which cointain coordinates, a timeline and values for each of those points for every timepoint.

Time___________1___________2 ___________3________4....

06:58:00.034    0,004508623 0,004181163 0,003086222 0,004710124

06:58:00.175    0,004592869 0,003782109 0,003253361 0,00379351

06:58:00.317    0,003992671 0,004261207 0,003144101 0,001365082

06:58:00.458    0,000380066 0,002662365 0,003144101 0,00379351

06:58:00.594    0,002403072 0,002318961 0,003431217 0,002363509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tested 250 simultaneous incidents, but I think `Time Manger` has enough capacity.

The data, on the other hand, will have to be re-formatted like below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i also thought about doing this and rounding the time on 0.00 but as i need that table for 24 hours that would be a table of 10fX10fx60sx60mx24h in lenght (8640000) - one 0 less if i make it 0.0 and those at least 864.000 x 250 Sensors i had 216.000.000 values in there then. wont qgis and timemanager crash?

Comment: @Las Will you edit your op and add that key information to your question? I am not sure how you are handling such a huge data. Are you on DB?

Comment: I tested a few ways and stacking the table like in your example seemed to be the best way. handling the data - i am using an enterprise program (sas) and gonna put a filter before the stacking so the data shrinks to an accetable size. thanks for your help :)